# How can I use rs.slaveOK() on mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I have checked the official document many times, it dose has the `rs.slaveOK()` function there and also the shell-help document.

[image: shell-help document]

I can't use `rs.slaveOK()` even if the function really exist.(Error occur)

That is so weird. Why is that?

The shell try to indicate me that `rs.slaveOK()` is not a function when I type it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use rs.slaveOk()"? Are you getting an error? SlaveOk doesn't execute anything, it's simply an option

Comment: @Peter4499 Yes, I mean that it will occur an error: `[main] TypeError: rs.slaveOK is not a function : @(shell):1:1`

Comment: What's the result of rs.Status()?

Comment: @Peter4499 It looks like that: `[main] ReferenceError: db is not defined :
rs.status@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1163:5`

Comment: @Peter4499 You must mean the command is `rs.status()`, not the `rs.Status()`. `Status()` function doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I mean status. So you're getting a error for that as well. You're not logged in to the right server or the server is not running

Comment: @Peter4499 I type the command just as authentic book say.`replicaSet = new ReplSetTest({"nodes": 3}); replicaSet.startSet(); replicaSet.initiate()`

Is that any problem there? Sorry, I'm newbie on MongoDB.

Comment: Simple thing since no one posted it yet... make sure you are typing rs.slaveOk() and NOT rs.slaveOK() .  MongoDB functions are case sensitive.

Comment: @dyouberg is correct: the error message "rs.slaveOK is not a function" indicates you tried to invoke the non-existent function `rs.slaveOK()` instead of the intended `rs.slaveOk()`.

Comment: @dyouberg Oh! I'm so careless...thank you so much. Please post your answer on the answer zone bellow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful! MongoDB functions are case sensitive:

rs.slaveOK() is not a function

rs.slaveOk() is the function you are looking for.

Comment: For MongoDB >= v4.2 the use of `secondaryOk()` is suggested as `rs.SlaveOk()` is getting deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You would use rs.slaveOk() when your Mongodb is set up as a replicaset, and you wish to query one of the secondary nodes, rather than the primary.  slaveOk is instructing the shell that its ok to return results from a secondary (rather than a primary) even though the results may not be entirely consistent with the primary.

I could be wrong, but it doesn't look like you are connected to a Mongodb which is configured as a replicaset, and if you are then I'm guessing that you are not connected to a secondary.  Therefore the instruction to query a secondary makes no sense.

Comment: It's about the case error. Thank you for your answer.